# AppDelegate and .xib are not implementing properly, but build is successful?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, delegates, xib

I really don't know how to explain this without pasting all my code, but ill give it a shot. "Assuming" my .hs and .ms are accurate, i have a feeling my .xib is not set correctly, but i cant really paste the code from that. Instead i've zipped the files and uploaded the source code. (if you are brave enough, it's here: http://bit.ly/ZtDkGi ) Im getting a successful build, but my emulator's screen is just black after the app launches.

Essentially, i had to manually add an appDelegate object. i set the class to the appropriate class - but its still not pulling. If someone would be kind enough to help, that would be great.

here's my Test_TableViewAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Test_TableViewAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;

@end
```

here's my **new** Test_TableViewAppDelegate.m

#import "Test_TableViewAppDelegate.h"

```
@implementation Test_TableViewAppDelegate

@synthesize window=_window;
@synthesize navController=_navController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.window = window;

UIViewController *fvc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *rootController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];

//UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fvc];
self.navController = nc;

//[self.window addSubview: nc.view];
//[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *petsArray;

}

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController
```

and last but not least, main.m ( i think this might be an issue too)

```
#import "Test_TableViewAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Test_TableViewAppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

thanks in advance. i'd appreciate it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your delegate `Test_TableViewAppDelegate`
why you adding views two times to the window?

```
// you could remove these two lines
[self.window addSubview: nc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];  

//keep these two lines
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And this view you are adding to the navigationController it is not  initalized with any nib name

```
UIViewController *fvc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

initialization should be like this instead in your delegate

```
RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];
```

Comment: ok i removed those two lines. still a green UIWindow under my nav controller. shouldnt i be seeing a UITableView over that green?

Comment: you should initialize the `UIViewController` with the nib Name you have in your interface

Comment: see my answer, you should use the ViewController which you are creating in your interface

Comment: in which file? RootViewController.m?

Comment: if your viewController name is RootViewController then you should declare that in your Delegate and use that to add to navigationController

Comment: ok i quit! ha. its been a long day. ill visit it in the morning. thanks for your help, really. ill be back tomorrow.

Comment: im still learning xcode and objective-c, so thanks for your patience. still learning the lingo and everything as well

Comment: ok. updated my code in test_tableviewappdelegate.m as per your suggestion. You can see it edited above. app crash :-/

Comment: post the crash? what is it saying, it is not big problem, you are just doing some minor mistake.

Comment: You can see the new .m above. :)

Comment: i would suggest you to first try with the sample applications of the apple, there are many tutorials if you start from there you will get to know how it works

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks anyway!

Comment: main.m is ok, there is nothing wrong in that, you have problem with your RootViewController, you can declare the RootViewController, you can declare the RootViewController as property and secondly you can add the navigationController you are createing to the window

Comment: i did that though, i thought. any chance you could be so kind as to look at my source code at the link?

Comment: wait a second the line you are creating NavigationController change it, to `self.navigation= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootController];`

Comment: that would be AWESOME! thank you :) im sure im just overlooking something. this is actually a tutorial im walking through. i did exactly what he did in the video, but mine is black. his is populating his array.

Comment: which tutorial you follow?

Comment: this may be a long shot, but the way i learn best is to look at "working" source code and go from there :) really its true. i can look at source code and see why it works, and learn, but its hard for me to learn by "edit this" and "edit that". any chance you could edit my zip file and send it back?

Comment: i would suggest you to follow this website, you can find good tutorials here http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that you're getting a black screen is that you are not properly allocating and initializing your navigation controller!

Instead, you should try this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // create the base window
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.window = window;

    [window release];

    // this is the home page from the user's perspective

    FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fvc];
    self.navigationController = nc;

    [fvc release];
    [nc release];

    // show them
    [self.window addSubview: nc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    return YES;
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: ok... it changed the black to green... but im still not able to see my array :) at least im making progress! any suggestions?

Comment: ok i just added your code to mine and edited it above. im getting green under the nav bar :D suggestions? again, you can download my whole source code and see what im doing wrong if you can. its really small. thanks!